# a map between group cohomology groups

Tags: group-cohomology

Consider a short exact sequence of (finite, or pro-finite) groups
$$
1 \to H \to G \xrightarrow{\pi} G/H \to 1
$$
and suppose for simplicity that $H$ lies in the centre of $G$. Such short exact sequence corresponds to a 2-cocycle in $H^2(G/H,H)$ under the correspodence between central extensions and second group cohomology. The cocycle is calculated as follows: take a section $j$ of $\pi$ and let
$$
h_{\sigma,\tau}=j(\sigma)+\sigma j(\tau) - j(\sigma\tau)
$$

My question is about a map 
$$
f: H^1(G,A^H) \to H^2(G/H,A^H)
$$
which is defined by a somewhat similar formula.

Take $\{g_\sigma\} \in H^1(G,A^H)$, take a section $j$ as above, and define the 2-cocycle as follows
$$
h_{\sigma,\tau}=g_{j(\sigma)}+j(\sigma)g_{j(\tau)}-g_{j(\sigma\tau)}
$$
One can check that the class of $h$ does not depend neither on a particular choice of a cocycle $g$ in a cohomology class, nor on the section $j$, the map is also functorial in $A$.

What is known about this map? Is it a part of some standard exact equence, or a composition of some well-known functors (like restriction/corestriction) ?

Comment: This is more of a guess but have you looked into papers on _equivariant_ group cohomology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the 1-cochain $\phi_g$ for the bar resolution of $G/H$ with values in $A^H$ given on the free generators $[x]: x \in G/H$ by $[x]\mapsto g(j(x))$.  Then $$\partial \phi_g [x|y] = \phi_g([x]+x[y]-[xy])=g(j(x)) + xg(j(y)) - g(j(xy))$$ (note the action of $x \in G/H$ is well-defined on $A^H$) which is your (second) map $h$.  Thus $h$ is zero in cohomology.

Comment: oh, you are right, of course. the context in which this map has arised made me believe that it might be non-zero. thanks!

Comment: Do you know about the 5-term exact sequence associated to the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for your group extension?  The cohomology groups you are talking about show up there.  It is in Benson - Representations and Cohomology vol 1 for example.

Comment: yes, in this sequence there is a term in between the two groups. If the composition of the two maps in this sequence were my map, consequently my map would have to be zero, but as I supposed that my map might be non-zero, I excluded this possibility.